# Saving contact form 7 data into custom Table

Tags: customization, forms, table, contact

I need save the *Contact Form 7* data in a custom table because the *Contact Form CFDB7* save me the information in the same colum.

some one khow a plugin make this or maybe a php functions for this?

Answer (score 2):

CF7 has an useful hook `wpcf7_submit` that can be used to process the data sent:

```
add_action("wpcf7_submit", "SE_379325_forward_cf7", 10, 2);

function SE_379325_forward_cf7($form, $result) {
  if( !class_exists('WPCF7_Submission') )
    return;
  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  if ($result["status"] == "mail_sent") { // proceed only if email has been sent 
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    save_posted_data($posted_data);
  }
};

// your insert function:
function save_posted_data($posted_data){
  //var_dump($posted_data); // $posted_data is an array containing all the form fields and values 
  $form_id = $posted_data["_wpcf7"]; // this is the post->ID of the submitted form so if you have more than one you can decide whether or not to save this form fields
  if($form_id !=2) // for exampe you may want to use only data coming from form # id 2
    return;
  global $wpdb;

  $wpdb->insert( 
     $wpdb->prefix.'{YOUR_TABLE}',
     array(
       '{column1}'=>$posted_data['your-name'],
       '{column2}'=>$posted_data['your-surname']
     ),
     array('%s','%s')
   );
}
```

If you want to process data before email is sent here's another hook:

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 
  // var_dump($contact_form);
};

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```

Consider also issue regarding validation on submission which are also involved in this process.

Here follows a
[List of available CF7 hooks»](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.5.1/hooks/#index=a)

be aware of the implications in terms of GDPR privacy compliance.